# Azure AD / Microsoft.Graph C# Authorization problem, but not in Graph Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio, active-directory

Hi all and thanks in advance for all feedback. It is much appreciated!

I use NuGet packages:
Microsoft.Graph 3.27.0
Micfosoft.Graph.Auth 1.0.0

and OnBehalfOfProvider and basically just want to list users or filter to a specific one from Azure Active Directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same as I am allowed to with Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). With the online explorer I have no issues:

[Everything fine with Graph Explorer and listing users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LLof.png)

But in my C# .NET application when I try to do the same
with scopes parameter:
string[] graphScopes = { "User.Read","profile", "Sites.ReadWrite.All"}; or
string[] graphScopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access"};

I get Status 500 Internal Server Error and these details:

> "error": {
> "code": "generalException",
> "message": "Unexpected exception returned from MSAL."
> ...
> "innerException": {
> "classification": 4,
> "statusCode": 400,
> "claims": null,
> "responseBody": "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The
> user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
> 'c0fb187f-daa8-4566-a7fb-2decd05ef980' named 'platform-test-ad'. Send
> an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

And with scopes parameter:
string[] graphScopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

I get 403:

> "error": {
> "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
> "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
> ...
> "statusCode": 403,
> "rawResponseBody": "{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",\r\n    "message": "Insufficient
> privileges to complete the operation."

Inside Azure, Enterprice applications | User settings looks like this:
[Enterprice applications User settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA8Zu.png)

and my C# code looks like this:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(authSettings.FunctionApplicationId)
                    .WithTenantId(authSettings.FunctionTenantId)
                    .WithAuthority(authSettings.Authority)
                    .WithClientSecret(authSettings.FunctionClientSecret)
                    .Build();
                string[] graphScopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access" };
                OnBehalfOfProvider authProvider = new OnBehalfOfProvider(confidentialClientApplication, graphScopes);

            var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token);
            var usersRequest = confidentialClientApplication.Users
                .Request()
                .WithUserAssertion(userAssertion);
            var usersResult = await usersRequest.GetAsync();
```

Any tips or explanation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your account is **not** a personal(invited) account when calling Microsoft Graph API to [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

And you need to add one of the **delegated** permission in API Permission from Azure portal, such as `User.Read.All`. The scope `User.Read` in your issue has not enough permissions.

[image]

```
string[] graphScopes = new string[] { "User.Read.All" };
OnBehalfOfProvider authProvider = new OnBehalfOfProvider(confidentialClientApplication, graphScopes);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

---

**Add:** click `grant admin consent for your tenant` in API permission, because the `User.Read.All` requires admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

It turnes out that [Pamela's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13308381/pamela-peng) answer was half of the answer, but it lead me to the solution.
I also needed to add permissions inside API permissions like this:
[API App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ndZ.png)

And to read single user, all users and create users inside Azure Active directory, I use this scope:

```
string[] graphScopes = { "User.ReadWrite.All" };
```

But for the above example you're right, "User.Read.All" was enough.

Answer (score -1):

I had some AADSTS65001 in the past with MSAL on AcquireTokenSilent when the scope where not fully written. For Powerbi I had to change

```
App.Read.All
```

to

```
https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/App.Read.All
```

Strangely the authenticate cycle was was perfectly working without this change (consent in particular) but failing only on AcquireTokenSilent.